# Edittext filter error on php and html

Tags: php, mysql, html

while entering the data in the textfield on the browser, it should fetch the data from the database and display accordingly. (ex: like google).
Here is my php code:

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","MobixMySQL") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("filter") or die(mysql_error());
    $partialStates = $_POST['partialStates'];
    $states = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM list1 WHERE name LIKE "%$partialStates%"");
    while($state = mysql_fetch_assoc($states)) {
    echo "<div>".$state['name']."</div>";
   }
   ?>
```

And below is my html code:

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function getStates(value){
     $.post("getStates.php",{partialStates:value},function(data){
     $("#results").html(data);
    });
    }
   </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" onKeyUp="getStates(this.value)" >
    <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Pls suggest me where am wrong....!!!

Comment: while entering the data in the textfield it is not fetching the data from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error with your quotes in the SQL...along with injection.  Check out [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) for future development

```
$partialStates = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['partialStates']);
$states = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM list1 WHERE `name` LIKE '%$partialStates%'");
```

**EDIT**

Since you're using jQuery trying changing your `onkeyup` event.  If you are still getting errors use something like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or your browsers javascript debugger to check for further errors.  Try the following (untested):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#myFilter').keyup(function(event) {
        $.post("getStates.php",{partialStates:$(this).val()},function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        });
    }).keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }  
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myFilter">
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: i tried but it cannot fetch the data from database to editext . while entering to the edittext

Comment: verify your `list1` table has the proper data. Use the command line to run your query to see check your query is structured properly.

Comment: the php code is correct. i feel there is mistake in html code . please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$states = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM list1 WHERE name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_strings($partialStates)."%'");
```

Instead of this

```
$states = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM list1 WHERE name LIKE "%$partialStates%"");
```

Comment: i tried but it cannot fetch the data from database to editext . while entering to the edittext

Comment: if still there is some error then it must be somewhere else than this code